# Prevent Upload Files from Napili Community

Tags: community, napili, upload, files

I have a Napili Community and inside I have the Files List standard component. Now I must hide the Upload Files button to prevent the users to upload files. How can I do that? 
Thanks

[This Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_files_list.htm&type=0) shows the component.

Comment: Just remove the component from any of your pages that use it by editing your pages or templates with the Editor. You can also edit the community user profile to remove file upload permissions.

Comment: Where Can I find file upload permission on the user profile? I searched it but I didn't find it. Thank you

Comment: Alas, it's not possible now. There is an idea, though, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KP6b to disallow users to upload files to chatter

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to restrict or limit what ALL Users in your Community can upload per [Limit Files in Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_file_limits.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> Community file moderation must be enabled for your org before you can limit files in your community. If you don’t see the option to limit files in Community Workspaces or Community Management, contact Salesforce.
>
> Your community file limits apply to files uploaded by community members anywhere in the community—in posts and comments, directly in the Files tab, and also from Salesforce1. You can also set community file limits using the SOAP API or Metadata API.
>
> Files uploaded before setting your file limits are unaffected. However, newer versions of those files must meet the limits you specify.
>
> Keep the following things in mind:
>
> - A file must meet the file limits set in the community in which it’s uploaded. For example, if a customer uploads a file on a case and then an agent uploads a newer version in your Salesforce internal org, the limits from the customer community still apply.
> - Files uploaded in your internal Salesforce org that are shared in a community aren’t subject to community file limits.

---

> 1. Open Community Workspaces or Community Management.
> 2. Select **Administration | Preferences**, then enter your limits in the Files section on the page.
>
>    - Maximum file size in MB—Enter a number between 3 MB and your org’s maximum file size. To use the default limit of 2 GB, leave this field empty or enter 0.
>    - Allow only these file types—Enter file extensions separated with a comma (for example: jpg,docx,txt). You can enter lowercase and uppercase letters. You can enter up to 1,000 characters. To allow all file types, leave this field empty.
> 3. Click **Save**.
>
> After you set your community’s file limits, members receive an error message if their file is larger than the size you set or if their file extension isn’t allowed.
>
> When a member tries to upload multiple files at once and a file is found that doesn’t meet your limits, none of the files are uploaded.

In essence, you'll want to restrict users from uploading **every** file type you can think of. This will apply to **all users** in your community.